# C++: Is there a significant speed difference between these two ways of writing numbers to a matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if there would be a significant speed/performance difference between the two following ways of storing numbers in the diagonal of a matrix:

Method 1:

```
//...
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(yindex = 0; yindex < yres; yindex += 1){
    for(xindex = 0; xindex < xres; xindex += 1){
        matrix[xindex][xindex] = 1;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
//...
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(yindex = 0; yindex < yres; yindex += 1){
    for(xindex = 0; xindex < xres; xindex += 1){

        if(xindex == yindex){
            matrix[xindex][yindex] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I would say that in *Method 1* the code is a little easier to read and more compact.
*Method 2* only writes to memory if the current matrix-element is on the diagonal where *Method 2* would write on every cycle of the for-loops.

Does Method 1 take significantly more time or performance especially with large values for `xres` and `yres`?
In this case I am trying to store the color values of an image in the matrix which means that `xres` and `yres` would have values somewhere around 500 - 2000.

Comment: Did you test and time the methods for the values you talk about? What happened? Which ended up being faster?

Comment: Both are a complete waste of CPU cycles. You only need one loop.

Comment: This is what benchmark software is for.  There is google-bench,ark you can use to get this information.  You can also use an online version at [quick-bench.com](http://quick-bench.com/)

Comment: Method1 uses xindex twice:  [xindex][xindex]

Comment: `matrix[xindex][xindex] = 1;` is undefined behavior, if `xres > yres`. Code working correctly > Code working fast.

Comment: @Technophile If you read the description - this is the intention.

Comment: Method 1 sets the diagonal multiple times. Method 2 demonstrates the classic "for/if" antipattern. They both iterator a row-major array in column-major order.

Comment: Why do you have two nested loops in the first place, if you are even *mentioning* efficiency?  You are turning an O(n) operation into O(n^2).

Comment: why has Method1 two loops? Anyhow, write code to be clear, readable and express intent. Transforming it to be most efficient is the compilers job.

Comment: @Mat This is the best I could come up with... What better ways are there?

Comment: @EVARATE One loop `int matrix[xres][yres] = {}; for(int  i = 0, dim = min(xres, yres); i < dim; ++i) { matrix[i][i] = 1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 has undefined behavior when `yres < xres`, so questions about its performance are moot. *(In this situation, there will be iterations where `yres <= xindex`. Since `xindex` is used for the index in both dimensions, this leads to an out-of-bounds array access.)* Broken code is simply a bad option, regardless of how quickly it breaks.

Method 2 has gratuitously bad performance (unless your compiler is smart enough to correct it for you). It has a loop that iterates multiple times, but that does something in at most one iteration. If someone gave you instructions along these lines, you would be justified in calling it busywork. (It's sort of like asking someone to guess the number you picked vs. telling that someone what number you picked.) This is better than broken code, but it shows a lack of understanding of what the instructions mean.

The first improvement to this method is to set `xindex` to the one used value, rather than iterate over all allowed values and checking to see if the current value is the desired value.

```
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(yindex = 0; yindex < yres; yindex += 1){
    xindex = yindex; // The only value for which we have something to do.
    if ( xindex < xres ){ // Keep this check from the old inner loop!
        matrix[xindex][yindex] = 1;
    }
}
```

Note that there is still a need to check `xindex < xres`. If this condition disappears, we end up with broken code, similar to how method 1 is broken.

The second improvement is to realize that there is no longer a need for two variables.

```
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(unsigned index = 0; index < yres; index += 1){
    if ( index < xres ){
        matrix[index][index] = 1;
    }
}
```

The third improvement involves recognizing that once the condition `index < xres` fails, it will fail for all larger values of `index`, hence for all later iterations. So we can move the condition into the loop.

```
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(unsigned index = 0; index < yres  &&  index < xres; index += 1){
    matrix[index][index] = 1;
}
```

There are still some stylistic changes that could be made at this point, but any effect they have on performance would be small compared to what's already been done. In fact, they probably will not affect performance at all if the code is compiled with basic optimizations. So it becomes more of a judgement call as to what is clearer to read.

```
int matrix[xres][yres];

for(unsigned index = 0; index < std::min(xres, yres); ++index){
    matrix[index][index] = 1;
}
```

If you were to fix method 1 then apply similar simplifications, you might end up with the same end result.